# Difference between -generic and -i386 kernel images

Tags: kernel, 32-bit, opengl

The regular auto-update installs the `-generic` linux image on my machine `intel core i3` machine. Is it better to use `-i386` kernel? What kind of machines `-generic` linux image supports?

The comment #5 at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/88693 is about the `OpenGL` applications are become faster on `-i386` kernel instead of `-generic` images. Is it as expected?

Comment: That bug report is marked as "Invalid", which means the bug report was never a valid bug. Therefore, referring to that bug is not useful in any way shape or form.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `-generic` is just a metapackage that pulls in the latest kernel for your architecture (presumably 64bit).
That bug report is very old and I don't think it should have any effect.